# How set CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS immediately after the executable file? [tcc -ar]

Tags: c, cmake, unix-ar, tcc

How set `CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS` in CMakeLists.txt immediately after the executable file?

for example:
I need:

`tcc.exe`**-ar**`qc staticRun.lib CMakeFiles/staticRun.dir/utils/system.c.obj`

but cmake after this settings:

> `set (CMAKE_AR C:/run/code/toolchains/c++/MinGW-tcc/bin/tcc.exe CACHE FILEPATH "" FORCE)`
>
> `set (CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS -ar CACHE STRING "" FORCE)`

add `-ar` key like this:

`tcc.exe qc staticRun.lib CMakeFiles/staticRun.dir/utils/system.c.obj`**-ar**

so, building the static library failed.

## P.S.

[tcc.exe](https://gitlab.com/janneke/tinycc/blob/master/win32/tcc-win32.txt#L104) -ar - mean

> Tools:
>     create library  : tcc -ar [rcsv] lib.a files

Comment: Try something along `set(CMAKE_C_CREATE_STATIC_LIBRARY "<CMAKE_AR> -ar qc <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>)` Or also like switch `<LINK_FLAGS>` with `<TARGET>`

Comment: Thanks, its works. You forget `"`. ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest is just to change the line that is used to run the static library with your custom semantics:

```
set(CMAKE_C_CREATE_STATIC_LIBRARY "<CMAKE_AR> -ar qc <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")
```

Comment: because https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/4b266927c7556f74d11d6f499360d682117e0a60/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake#L159