# How to make cmake pass D argument to ar for reproducible build of a static library

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries

My project uses CMake to build both static and dynamic libraries from the same C++ code. The dynamic library file (.so) stays the same on rebuild, but the static library file (.a) changes on every rebuild. I have come to understand that it's because of the behaviour of `ar` tool and I need to pass D argument to create deterministic output.

I've found a cmake variable `CMAKE_AR`, which points to `/usr/bin/ar` on my machine. The compile output shows that the command executed is: `/usr/bin/ar qc libfoo.a file1.o file2.o ...`.

From `ar` documentation, I should be changing the above invocation to `/usr/bin/ar qcD ...` for deterministic output.

How do I accomplish this with CMake?

I'm on Linux and need a solution compatible with CMake >= v3.11

Comment: You may add your additional options to the `CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS` variable, e.g. `set(CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS} D")`

Comment: @vre That doesn't work. It results in: `/usr/bin/ar qc libfoo.a D file1.o file2.o ...`.

Comment: This question provides additional information and a possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62339192/how-set-cmake-static-linker-flags-immediately-after-the-executable-file-tcc-a

Comment: @vre Thanks a lot for that link. Although the method in that didn't quite work, there was a link to CMake git repo that helped.
`set(CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_CREATE "<CMAKE_AR> qcD <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")` seems to do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works to set arguments for `ar` and `ranlib` for generating deterministic static library output files:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_CREATE "<CMAKE_AR> qcD <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")
set(CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_FINISH "<CMAKE_RANLIB> -D <TARGET>")
```